# Why is spyder not recognized as an internal or external command when installed as standalone?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I already have Python (3.7) and I didn't want to install whole Anaconda, so I used standalone Spyder installer. However, now when I try to run Spyder from cmd I get `'spyder' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. The solutions I found suggest reinstalling it with Anaconda, is there no way to fix it without Anaconda?

Comment: Find out what directory `spyder.exe` is in, then add that directory to your `PATH`.

Comment: QUICK AND DIRTY: You could add spyder to your environment variables (so whatever console you write 'spyder' in will work) find the .exe of spyder and follow the procedure:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk

Comment: For future references (people who have the same problem), could make it a question? It's important. "Why is spyder not recognized as an internal or external command?". I hope we solved your problem. ;)

Comment: If you consider [all the other things](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command) that might be "not recognized as an internal or external command", perhaps a pattern emerges?

Comment: How exactly did you run the installer? Did it say anything about where Spyder was being installed? Where is it?

Comment: Hi, I just clicked on the Download button on https://www.spyder-ide.org/.

Comment: I wanted to try adding `spyder.exe` to path but there seems to be no such file on my computer. I only found the Spyder folder at C:\Program Files\Spyder but no `spyder.exe` inside